# array to string (php)

Tags: php, arrays, string

Please help me to convert array to string.

array look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [red] => 255
                    [green] => 255
                    [blue] => 255
                    [alpha] => 127
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [red] => 255
                    [green] => 255
                    [blue] => 255
                    [alpha] => 127
                )
             ...

        )

)
```

I tried to use the implode function, but no result...

```
$string = implode(", ", $pxlCorArr);
```

PS: Sorry for my english i from ukraine.

Comment: What do you want the output string to look like?

Comment: You would surely get _some result_ but it looks like [you are converting a 2 dimensional array to a string](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+implode+multi+dimensional). As Tim asked, what should the output look like?

Comment: i whant to output red,green,blue,alpha

Comment: @VolodyaDaniliv Do you want an _array_ of strings red,green,blue,alpha?

Comment: yes, i need one string like this: 255.255.255.127,255.255.255.123,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be another possibility, as a function to which you pass your initial array and the function returns the string you needed:

```
function getRGBAlpha($pxlCorArr) {

    $rgbVals = array();
    foreach($pxlCorArr as $subArr) {
        if(is_array($subArr)) {
            foreach($subArr as $colValues) {
                $rgbVals[] = implode('.', $colValues);
            }
        }
    }

    return implode(',', $rgbVals);
}
```

and so you could do the following, somewhere in your code, to get the output you needed:

```
echo getRGBAlpha($pxlCorArr);
```

should output:

```
255.255.255.127,255.255.255.127
```

Answer (score 5):

Array:

```
$pxlCorArr = 
  array(
      array (
           array('red' => 255, 
                 'green' => 255,
                 'blue' => 255,
                 'alpha' => 127
           ),

           array('red' => 255,
                 'green' => 255,
                 'blue' => 255,
                 'alpha' => 127
           )
      )
  );
```

Code:

```
$output = '';
foreach ($pxlCorArr as $subArray) {
    if(is_array($subArray)) {
        foreach ($subArray as $subArray2) {
            if(is_array($subArray2)) {
                $output .= implode ('.', $subArray);
                $output .= ',';
            }
        }
    }
}
$output = rtrim($output, ',');
```

Output:

> 255.255.255.127,255.255.255.127

Comment: `implode()` would be less expensive, instead of the whole concatenation and trimming ;-)

Comment: tell me please where i need to insert input array

Comment: just change $array to the name of your array, which I guess is $pxlCorArr, right?

Comment: thx! but result is: Array.Array.Array.Array.Array.Array.Array.Array.Array.

Comment: can you help me to fix this trouble?

Comment: It was at title of example, but you're right yes... Lemme correct the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [red] => 255
                    [green] => 255
                    [blue] => 255
                    [alpha] => 127
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [red] => 255
                    [green] => 255
                    [blue] => 255
                    [alpha] => 127
                )
             ...

        )

)


$string = '';
$array = $exists_array[0];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
$string .= $key." : ".$value."\n";
}
print $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using array_walk over lambda function:

```
  $implodevals =  create_function('&$val', '$val = implode(".", $val);');
  array_walk($array, $implodevals);
  print rtrim(implode(", ", $array), ",");
```

Input array:

```
   $array = Array
    (
        0 => Array
            (
                "red" => 255,
                "green" => 255,
                "blue" => 255,
                "alpha" => 127
            ),

        1 => Array
            (
                "red" => 255,
                "green" => 255,
                "blue" => 255,
                "alpha" => 127,
            )



     );
```